# Live streaming RTSP feed to local network HTTP using VLC

Tags: html, http, stream, vlc, rtsp

I'm trying to stream a RTSP feed (from ABUS camera) over the local network trough a website using VLC. I've tried to apply all the solutions I've found here or elsewhere, no success till now.

I need to capture the feed from `rtsp://192.168.0.2:554/stream1` and convert it with VLC to `192.168.0.2:1234/stream.ogg` file. VLC keep crashes. Without transcoding it doesn't crash but I have no stream file.

I'm using XAMP (and WAMP also) as a webserver on Windows 7 and 10. I can't make it work, regardless what I'm trying. As HTML Player I'm using Projekktor and here is my code line:

```
<video id="player_a" class="projekktor" poster="intro.png" title="RTS Stream" controls autoplay loop>
<source src="http://192.168.2.103:1234/stream.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
projekktor('#player_a', {
volume: 0.0,
playerFlashMP4: 'http://localhost:6969/streaming/js/projekktor/swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback_hls.swf',
playerFlashMP3: 'http://localhost:6969/streaming/js/projekktor/swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
platforms: ['browser', 'android', 'ios', 'vlc', 'native', 'flash'],
});
});
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution, using flash player and VLC browser plugin.

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  width="100%"  height="100%" id="vlc" loop="yes" autoplay="yes" controls="false" target="rtsp://192.168.0.2:554/stream1"></embed>
```

Comment: "This plugin is not supported" :(